# What is this fighter jet at Weymouth NAS?

Tags: aircraft-identification, fighter

The picture was taken at Weymouth NAS in about 1988
[image: unknown fighter jet]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a [Panavia Tornado.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panavia_Tornado)

[Found a site with that picture](https://sites.google.com/site/weymouthnasairshow/) and others from the same air show. [Here is a better picture of one in the same markings.](https://www.flickr.com/photos/tristartech/16936032219) It is part of the [RAF No. 5 Squadron,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No._5_Squadron_RAF) which switched from the English Electric Lightning to the Tornado in 1988. The squadron uses a maple leaf to commemorate their link to the Canadian Corps in World War 1.

[image]
<sup>[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RAF_Tornado_GR4_MOD_45155233.jpg)</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! In fact that website is mine! I made it so long ago I kind of forgot about it. Senior moments!

Comment: @tom37 glad I could help! I also noticed there's another picture of a Tornado in different markings with the file name tornado.jpg but the one you posted is unkn.jpg. At least to me the maple leaf threw me off because Canada didn't use them.

Comment: Wow! I'm so glad I found this site! I'm going to put 5 more that have stumped me as well

Comment: What is that on the port wing tip? Doesn’t appear to be Meteor, instrumentation?

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz I thought it might be a targeting pod, but looking at all the targeting pods that have ever been fitted to Tornados, none look like that. So... I know what it isn't :)

Comment: The one in the OPs photo is an ADV, the one in your photo is a GR4 - both variants of a Panavia Tornado but both very very different :)

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Perhaps an ECM pod? Looks like there's some ground targeting/intelligence photography equipment under the cockpit also, which would pair well with ECM. Ah, Wikipedia says one of the devices under the cockpit is a FLIR, so ground targeting and not photography.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz Yeah an image on this page says it's an ECM pod: http://zarco-macross.wikidot.com/wiki:panavia-tornado

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be a [Panavia Tornado](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panavia_Tornado).

Answer (score 4):

It is a Panavia Tornado F3, Number: ZG796  in RAF service.
See [this link](https://www.mediastorehouse.com/flightglobal/modern-aircraft/panavia-tornado-raf-a-a-refuelling-1565667.html) for a nicer pic.
Very hard to read the tail number in this photo, but matches well with that noted in the link, and a unique (?) livery.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Tornado F3 of 5 Sqn. Also known as the Tornado ADV (air defence variant) in foreign air forces.

Comment: You're talking to people from all around the world, so it's best not to use "foreign" when you mean "not from one particular country".

Comment: Hi and welcome. Both facts are already in other answers. It's preferable to add new information.